# Thumb drives and external hard drives no longer visible - Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, usb-drive, disk-management

I can no longer see (previously working) USB attached devices (thumb drives and external hard drives) on my Ubuntu 18.04 computer.  When I attached one of these devices I hear the tell-tale sound that the device is attaching.  I can see these devices in Disks.  I can not access the devices in PCmanFM, Thunar, or Nautilus because there is no drive shown.

My bluetooth mouse and USB keyboard are working just fine.

I did do an update and install Minecraft recently and these are the only changes to happen on the computer.

Upon recognizing the problem I did another update and restarted the computer but this did not solve the problem.

How do I get these external storage devices to show in my file browser?  Why did this happen in the first place?

Please know that I am relatively new to Ubuntu so please answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the USB is detected by your computer but not automatically mounted for some reason. First fire up the terminal and make sure the USB is *not* attached to your computer before listing the devices available, as follows:

```bsh
$ ls /dev # list all device nodes
/dev/sda /dev/sda1 /dev/sda2
```

You might see different output depending on how your hard drive is partitioned, etc. Now attach your USB and re-run the command after hearing the sound to see which new devices are available:

```bsh
$ ls /dev # list all device nodes
/dev/sda /dev/sda1 /dev/sda2 /dev/sdb /dev/sdb1
```

In my case, the device node associated with my USB is `/dev/sdb`. Then double-check that the USB is *not* currently mounted by running:

```bsh
$ mount | grep /dev/sdb # Replace /dev/sdb with the device node associated with your USB as appropriate
```

If there is no output from the above command then your USB is not mounted. In that case, create an empty folder under `/media/student` as follows (assuming your username is `student` - replace with your own username accordingly):

```bsh
$ sudo mkdir /media/student/my-usb # Replace 'student' with your username as appropriate
```

... and mount your USB partition on that folder, as follows:

```bsh
$ sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /media/student/my-usb # Replace "sdb1" and "student" with your own USB partition and username respectively as appropriate
```

If successful, you should now be able to access the files in your USB via `/media/student/my-usb`.